# How to Limit Used devices in Salesforce Connected iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication, salesforce

Can I set up my salesforce connected app so that it will only allow one user to sign into the phone, like the salesforce mobile app. I want to prevent our users from buying one license and sharing that license among ten mobile app users.

Comment: Anyone please respond. Its urgent.

Comment: You can ask Salesforce questions directly on salesforce.stackexchange.com